# Java Merge 2 separate lists inside loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a composite VO like below;

```
MyCompositeVO {
    MyActionVO myAction;
    MyPartnerVO partner;
}
```

I want to return a list of this composite object as below;

```
List<MyCompositeVO> results = new ArrayList<MyCompositeVO>();
```

Also through query execution, I get the below 2 lists;

```
List<MyAction> myActions;
List<MyPartnerVO> myPartnerVOList;
```

There is a common attribute in each of these classes; **myPartnerId** (might be useful for merging)

Now I want to kind of loop through these lists and return the merged output. My rough code for the same looks like below;

```
MyCompositeVO compositeVO = new MyCompositeVO();

for (MyPartnerVO myPartner : myPartnerVOList) {
    compositeVO.setPartner(myPartner);
}

for (MyAction action : myActions) {
    MyActionVO myActionVO = new MyActionVO();
    partnerActionVO.copyPropertiesFrom(action);
    compositeVO.setMyAction(myActionVO);
}

results.add(compositeVO);
```

How do I merge the above 2 loops and return the final output in "results" ?

**Note:**
It is possible that there is nothing in "myActions" and in that case 
compositeVO.setMyAction() needs to be set as null

Comment: Is the size of both lists the same?

Comment: No...like I said, one of them can be blank

Answer (score 0):

You need an external loop that goes through your partners (I assume from your description that they are the important part of the final object). For each partner, you then loop around and look for a matching action.

My code below assumes the presence of a few functions and presumes your action will be suitably `null` if no matching one is found.

```
for (MyPartnerVO myPartner : myPartnerVOList) {

  MyCompositeVO compositeVO = new MyCompositeVO();
  compositeVO.setPartner(myPartner);  

  for (MyAction action : myActions) {
    if (action.getPartnerID() == myPartner.getID()) { // or .equals()
      MyActionVO myActionVO = new MyActionVO();
      myActionVO.copyPropertiesFrom(action);
      compositeVO.setMyAction(myActionVO);
      break;
    }
  }

  results.add(compositeVO);
}
```